# external-graphic relative path

Tags: java, java-8, apache-fop

How do I use fo:external-graphic with a relative path?

I've been looking about every where but I can not find an answer. Most of the answers talk about putting the image into the resource of my Java project, but that wont do the trick for me since it is an image that it generated run time.

So in short .. Can I put some kind of variable into my XSL document and then via a callback set it in my java code?

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block margin-top="23mm">
        <fo:external-graphic src="url({$ImagePath}CAPTION.PNG)" height="17mm" 
                             content-height="scale-to-fit"      content-width="65mm"
                             scaling="non-uniform"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Parameters!

In your XSL document first you have to define your variable:

Then later on you can use it:

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block margin-top="23mm">
        <fo:external-graphic src="url({$ImagePath}CAPTION.PNG)" height="17mm" 
                             content-height="scale-to-fit"      content-width="65mm"
                             scaling="non-uniform"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Before rendering your document you have you set the variable in your JAVA Code:

// Setup XSLT
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));

```
        // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        transformer.setParameter("ImagePath", "C:/Temp/Poland/");
        transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
```